# Cannot remove mouseover event on Div

Tags: javascript

I have a weird kind of problem.I have hover event on DIV .On run time i have to insert some elements in to DIV .Hover event should not happen after inserting div elements.But problem is if i hover on DIV before inserting elements in to the DIV .Hover event is getting carried after inserting the elements.I tried removing attribute its not working for me...

Please let me know If you have a solution

Comment: How about a little code to see what you have going on here.

Comment: Definitely need to see some code here.  There are multiple ways you can attach and detach event handlers and to top it off it sounds like you're using a framework (because there is no `.hover` event in DOM).

Answer (score 0):

As gmcalab said, please provide some code.

But, a wild shot from here. Since a class is always applied to an element, no matter the state of that element. Maybe you can write a little javascript to change the class of the DIV after you're done.

```
<div id="yourdiv" class="foo">
```

You do your things and finally call:

```
document.getElementById('yourdiv').className = 'bar';
```

Then in css something like

```
.bar:hover { background:#EDEDED; or-whatever-styling:you-need;}
```

But then again, without a codesample it's a hard guess...